# Fourier series expansion - An and Bn both coming to 0

Tags: fourier-series

So I am learning how to do Fourier series expansions by writing the function expression from given graphs:

- To find the series, we calculate $A_{0}, A_{n}$ and $B_{n}$ and plug those values in the main Fourier series formula and get a few trigonometric components expansions.
- However, the problem I am facing is both my $A_{n}$ and $B_{n}$ come to $0$ after doing the integration which is unusual.
- I have written the function below with the limits I am using in the math and also attached a photo of the figure.
  $$
  \operatorname{f}\left(x\right) =
  \left\{\begin{array}{lcl}
  {\displaystyle x + \pi} & \mbox{if} &
  {\displaystyle -\pi < x < 0}
  \\[1mm]
  {\displaystyle \pi - x} & \mbox{if} &
  {\displaystyle \phantom{-}0 < x < \pi}
  \end{array}\right.
  $$
  I would really appreciate it if anyone solve this math/tell me what am I doing wrong. Thank you.

[Graph:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFIVG.png)

Comment: Can you show the calculation that you have done which makes $A_n$ and $B_n$ both $0$? We can help you with checking the steps

Comment: @ĐàoMinhDũng its on my notebook :/

Comment: Can you take a picture of it and post on some pages like https://postimages.org/, and share the link to us?

Answer (score 1):

$$
\operatorname{f}\left(x\right) =
a_{0} + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}a_{n}\cos\left(nx\right)
$$

---

\begin{align}
&\overbrace{%
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\operatorname{f}\left(x\right)\,\mathrm{d}x}
^{\displaystyle \pi^{2}}\ =\ a_{0}\
\overbrace{\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\mathrm{d}x}^{\displaystyle 2\pi}\ +\
\overbrace{\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}a_{n}\cos\left(nx\right)\,\mathrm{d}x}
^{\displaystyle 0}
\\ &\
\implies \bbox[10px,border:1px ridge navy]{a_{0} =
{\pi \over 2}} \\ &
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
&\overbrace{%
{1 \over \pi}
\int_{\pi}^{\pi}\operatorname{f}\left(x\right)
\cos\left(nx\right)\,\mathrm{d}x}
^{\displaystyle {2 \over \pi}{1 - \left(-1\right)^{n} \over n^{2}}} =
a_{0}\,{1 \over \pi}\
\overbrace{\int_{\pi}^{\pi}
\cos\left(nx\right)\,\mathrm{d}x}^{\displaystyle 0}\ \\ + &\
\overbrace{{1 \over \pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos\left(nx\right)\sum_{m = 1}^{\infty}a_{m}\cos\left(mx\right)\,\mathrm{d}x}
^{\displaystyle a_{n}}
\\[5mm] &\
\implies \bbox[10px,border:1px ridge navy]{\left.
\vphantom{\Large A}a_{n}\,\right\vert_{n\ \geq\ 1} =
{2 \over \pi}{1 - \left(-1\right)^{n} \over n^{2}}} \\ &
\end{align}

---

$$
\bbox[10px,border:1px ridge navy]{\operatorname{f}\left(x\right) =
{\pi \over 2} +
{4 \over \pi}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
{\cos\left(\left[2n + 1\right]x\right) \over \left(2n + 1\right)^{2}}} \\
$$

Comment: thank you sir. could you recommend a good website for graphing the above fourier series?

Comment: @AW [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5BPi%2F2+%2B+%284%2FPi%29+Sum%5BCos%5B%282+n+%2B+1%29+x%5D%2F%282+n+%2B+1%29%5E2%2C+%7Bn%2C+0%2C+Infinity%7D%5D%2C%7Bx%2C-Pi%2CPi%7D%5D). It's free but you can upgrade (you have to pay) to enjoy the full features.

Comment: thanks, I will  check it out!

Answer (score 0):

You are mostly likely doing the integration wrong. Don't rush it because its a easy integral. Notice its a even function, so its Fourier series is a cosine series, and its enough to calculate over $(0,\pi)$, i.e. $$a_n=\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x)\cos(nx) dx =  \frac{2}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} f(x)\cos(nx) dx$$

and this integral is not zero.

Comment: thanks, i got it.  an= 2((-1)^n-1)/pi.n^2